# Is there a way to backup an individual partition that is part of a logical volume?

Tags: partitioning, backup, lvm

Is there a way to backup an individual partition that is part of a logical volume? I would like to do an automated regular snapshot that is compressed if possible.

Comment: You can back it up with several methods, the only thing unique to lvm is lvm snapshots. See http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/snapshots_backup.html and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem

Comment: If I had a logical volume "storage" which consisted of partitions sdb1 and sdc1 could I then do the following:  "sudo tar -cpzf /mnt/drive/sdb1_backup.tar.gz /dev/sdb1"  would this create a backup of the data on the partition or would this be a complete waste of time?

Comment: Are these logical volumes LVM ? mount them somewhere /mnt/storage and then tar should work. You should test restoring it though ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you mean with "Is there a way to backup an individual partition that is part of a logical volume?" there are a few possible answers:

***Can I continue using my current back-up software to back-up?***

Yes, you can, it's just another partition..

***Can I clone the partition easily for redeployment somewhere else?***

Yes, you can if you set up the LVMs on the other machine like you did on the first. (or clone the entire system is possible as well)

***What are the new ways of efficiently backing up with my brand-new LVM partitions?***

One word: snapshots!  :-)

Head to [The Linux Documentation Project](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/snapshotintro.html) for [more info](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LVM-HOWTO/snapshots_backup.html) on snapshots.

Comment: Does LVM snapshot take a snapshot of the entire volume only or can it take a snapshot of the logical volume's individual parts (physical drives or LVM2 partitions that make up the logical volume).  also I don't know that this is relevant but I am using the system-config-lvm utility GUI.

Comment: Entire volume only...  Please don't forget to press the little grey check-mark below the "0" to accept the answer...  ;-)

Comment: Thinking about it now, *why* would you want to back up one drive of a RAID array, or one physical part of a logical volume?  You wouldn't be able to restore just part of those...  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I do not want a RAID array, I said that I want to get RAID 5 like redundancy without using RAID 5.  RAID 5 stripes data across all drives in the array then takes the data from one drive and makes a parity backup of that data striped across all other drives in the array, and it does this for all drives in the array thus the equivalent of one drive is lost to parity. If one drive fails a new drive can be placed in the array and the array will reconstruct the data from parity, but if two drives fail at approx. the same time all data is lost because the data and parity blocks are striped.

Comment: As I understand it with LVM you can make a spanned volume and you can add volumes on to it with out affecting the data on either volume. As such you could swap a disk out, format a lvm2 partition on the drive, mount it as a new volume, place the data from the backup on it, and then add it to the original volume!  Am I missing something?

Comment: correction:  I think what I meant was linear not spanned.

Comment: LVM is just what it means: Logical Volume Manager.  It's an abstraction layer on top of the physical hard drives.  *you don't know where data is stored exactly in an LVM*, just like with file systems...  Suppose you create a partition in which you store /tmp and /home and now you want to back up only those sectors of /home?  Not impossible, but...  Easier to create 2 partitions for /home and /tmp and only back up /home.  Same with Logical Volumes: you have 3 hard disks which you logically define into 5 logical partitions *and you don't know which sectors on what hard drive contain /home*

Comment: Alright, so I've misunderstood what LVM is capable of. But I think I know how to do what I want using a virtual machine. Thank you Fabby for your patients with me.  I am sure that you were ready to do a massive facepalm.